# Send data between two pages with jQuery/AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax, long-polling

I am looking for a way to send data between two different Divs on two different pages, both are on the same domain.

This is more of a learning exercise as I am very new to jQuery and AJAX, I have been searching  for a simple way of doing this but most answers or options seem to be complex and involve installing other software , etc.

I would like to have one html page listening for an event, the other html page will send an event when something happens, for example;

Page 1 - Countdown clock, every time it reaches a new hour it sends the data to Page 2

Page 2 - Listening for this data, when received it displays the data in a div

This is not exactly what I want to do in regards to the Countdown clock, it is just an example but the theory is what I need. Is it possible to set this up with just 2 flat html pages and some jQuery/AJAX code? It does not need to be secure or optimized , like I said it is just for learning.

Comment: You will have to process the data server side. HTML alone won't do it since it is running on the client's side.

Comment: Ya, typically, you should use a database server side and make pages requesting this database using ajax

Comment: Is it possible to do this without a database? I was hoping for something a little faster, Can data not just be sent from one html page to another using ajax and jquery?

Comment: What you can do is getting a random div from another html file every hour (but not send data and expect a response depending on the sent data, that's just server-side. HTML has no processing power in this regard, nor can it access the data)

Comment: What about web sockets? Would I need to look more into Node JS and Socket IO for this?

Comment: WebSockets are complex and powerful, for this simpler case HTML5 Server Sent Events would do the job (in node or any other server, and browsers that support SSE).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you'd look to the [nodejs](http://nodejs.org/) and [socket.io](http://socket.io/) 
This is amazing tools that do all thing to make interactions by javascript.

Comment: Thank you, to use these tools for what I am trying to do would you say it fairly simple? I have no experience with these tools

Comment: It is quite simple. And you'll take good experience :)
Do you want work in windows or linux?

Comment: Ah thnak you, It will mainly be Linux

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is, install a server ([wamp](http://www.wampserver.com/) for example), and then you can communicate between your pages, by using database or files, and then use something like that:

**Page 1:**

```
<a id="sendData">Send Data to Page 2 </a>

var url = http://localhost/yoursite/writeToFile.php
$('a#sendData').click(
               $.ajax({ url: url, type: "POST", data:{test:'test'} })
                .done(function() {
                      $(this).append(' sent!');
               });
)};
```

**Page 2:**

```
<div>Listening to Page 1 </div>

window.setInterval(function(){
 listenToPage1();
}, 5000);

 function listenToPage1()
{
    var url = http://localhost/yoursite/readFromFile.php
    $.get(url, function(data) { $('div').html(data);   });
}
```

**writeToFile.php**

```
<?php
   $fp = fopen('data.txt', 'a');
   fwrite($fp, $_POST);
   fclose($fp);
?>
```

**readFromFile.php**

```
<?php 
   readfile('data.txt');
?>
```

**yoursite folder:**

```
www/
  /yousite
   readFromFile.php
   writeToFile.php
   page1.php
   page2.php
   data.txt
```

And of course you can use `nodejs` to make interactions directly by `javascript`, but I think it's better to start by learning the basics and then you can move to `nodejs` (it doesn't mean `nodejs` is very complicated :p)

Comment: This is brilliant thank you, I don't think I realized the size of the task when I originally thought about it! I will try this out, I am worried that using a database will be slow? If there is a change every few seconds?

Comment: I think, it's better to start by using files it's more easiest than databases (again doesn't mean it's complicated), for databases delay, it all depends on your database size ...